I dont have intellisense in django while im using vscode
The Problem:
My VS Code doesn't have IntelliSense for the following:

settings.py: no IntelliSense;

when importing settings from django.conf:


from django.conf import settings

a = settings. # no IntelliSense after the dot (attempting dot-notation)


When using filter, get, etc. in .objects, I don't have any IntelliSense:

from .models import Account

user: Account = Account.objects.get() 
# I don't have IntelliSense in .get() method even with filtering with Q method


i dont have intellisence in revese , revese_laze and {% url %} tag:

from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import RegisterForm

my_url = reverse("") # idont have itenlisence in this met

class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = "account_module/register-page.html"
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("") # i don have IntelliSense here too

html:
<a hred="{% url "" args=kwarg %}"> register </a>

{% comment %} IntelliSense for url tag too (for url name args and kwargs) {% endcomment %}

Attempted Solutions:
I tried installing extensions like django, django-intellisense, django template but they don't work.
I also tried using mypy and django-stubs but they don't work either.
Finally, I tried changing my VS Code settings but none of them worked.
My Settings:
{
    "djangointellisense.projectRoot": "C:/path/myprojectname",
    "djangointellisense.settingsModule": "myprojecctname.settings",
    "djangointellisense.debugMessages": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["C:/path/myprojectname"],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/path/myprojectname"],
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
}


It looks like you may have a typo in your djangointellisense.settingsModule setting: myprojecctname.settings** -> myprojectname.settings. This may help resolve some of the issues you're experiencing.

Install these two vscode Microsoft extensions. they will help you. python and intellicode

I try them but ther dont work
